# database query in action.class move to lib/model

Tags: php, oop, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

i have:

```
  public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
            $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Messages')
            ->where('id = ?', $id);
            $query->fetchArray();
  }
```

i did function in lib/model:

```
        public function newfunction($id)
    {
            $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('Messages')
            ->where('id = ?', $id);

            return $query->fetchArray();

    }
```

and now have:

```
  public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
         $this->newfunction($id);
  }
```

but i have error:

sfException: Call to undefined method messagesActions::newfunction.

if :

```
  public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
         $this->newfunction($id);
  }
```

i have

`Fatal error: Call to a member function newFunction() on a non-object in`

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you created `newFunction` in `lib/model/MessagesTable.class.php`.

`$this->newFunction()` won't work, because `$this` refers to the current action instance, not your model's table. You need to use either:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable("Messages")->newFunction($id);
```

or

```
MessagesTable::getInstance()->newFunction($id);
```

they both do the same thing, so it's just a matter of preference.

Also, you do not set a value for `$id` in your action's code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you problem here is that you used a non static method in order to fetch an object using a query and the "this" reference is giving you a sfAction instance in:

```
 public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
         $this->newfunction($id);
  }
```

I would suggest to change your newfunction declaration in the model class to be something like this (create this funciton in /lib/model/Doctrine/MessagesTable.class.php):

```
public static newfunction($id)
{
    $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Messages')
    ->where('id = ?', $id);

    return $query->fetchArray();
}
```

Now your action should look something like this:

```
  public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    [..]//i'm assuming that id is set somewhere before this and is valid
         MessagesTable::newfunction($id); 
  }
```

Comment: adding static didn't help. what is it FunctionClass:: ?

Comment: You mentioned creating a function in lib/model, but you did not specified in witch class so i used FunctionClass in order to define the class name of the funciton in witch you created that method

Comment: /lib/model/Doctrine/MessagesTable.class.php .
when i make $this->newfunction($id); i have: Call to undefined method planActions::updatePlans.
if $messages->newfunction($id); i have: Notice: Undefined variable: messages in

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take advantage with the 'Magic methods' that Doctrine provides?

That query could be like this:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable("Messages")->findById($id);
```

And then, you wont need to define a new method.
To see more, look at de documentation page of doctrine, into de [magic method findBy*](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/dql-doctrine-query-language%3amagic-finders)